# [UINavigationController setGoalName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7964e2c0

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios8

I have created the app with following code. Its working fine with iOS7 but it throws the below error when I run with iOS8.

```
[UINavigationController setGoalName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7964e2c0
```

My firstViewcontroller.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

GoalDetailsViewController *goalsDetailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[self.arrCategoryTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfCategory]]);
goalsDetailsViewController.goalName = @"Exercise Daily";

}
```

My GoalDetailsViewController.h

```
@interface GoalDetailsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic) NSString *goalName;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `prepareForSegue:sender:` and examine the `destinationViewController`. It is probably not an actual instance of `GoalDetailsViewController`, and thus will not recognize the `setGoalName:` selector. My guess is that iOS 8 is sending you another view controller that you weren't expecting.

Comment: It would appear that `goalsDetailsViewController` is a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like your destinationviewcontroller is a subclass of UINAvigationController.

Try this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

GoalDetailsViewController *goalsDetailsViewController = [(UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController topViewController];
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[self.arrCategoryTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfCategory]]);
goalsDetailsViewController.goalName = @"Exercise Daily";

}
```

Comment: YourViewController *Controller = (YourViewController*)[segue.destinationViewController topViewController];

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to handle this crash would be to simply make sure that the `destinationViewController` is of the type you're expecting before you attempt to set a property on it. Something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    GoalDetailsViewController *goalsDetailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[self.arrCategoryTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfCategory]]);

    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[GoalDetailsViewController class]]) {
        GoalDetailsViewController *goalsDetailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        goalsDetailsViewController.goalName = @"Exercise Daily";
    }
}
```

This change ensures that the `destinationViewController` is of kind `GoalDetailsViewController` before treating it as such.