# iOS7 and iOS8 segue.destinationViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to make my app work with both iOS7 and iOS8 and I ran into a problem in my prepareForSegue methods in my view controllers.

**In iOS8** `segue.destinationViewController` is of class UINavigationController, so I use `[[segue.desinationViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]` which works fine, but **in iOS7** `segue.desinationViewController` is of class CMAMyViewControllerClassName, which will obviously throw an error when I try to send a `viewContollers` message to it.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172933/uinavigationcontroller-setgoalname-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-0x) solution which will work, but I was wondering if there's a better solution? Other than the latter post I haven't been able to find anything about it. If there's not a "proper" solution, I'll create a method that gets the correct view controller; I was just wondering how other people handled this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are the destination controllers different? Are you using different storyboards for the two different targets?

Comment: I'm not sure why they are different; I just assumed it was changed for iOS8. And no, I'm not, I'm using one storyboard.

Comment: As far as I know this shouldn't have changed between iOS 7 and 8. How are you testing this? Do you have 2 different apps, one for 7 and one for 8, or two targets, or what?

Comment: One app, an iPhone 6 simulator with iOS 8.1 and an iPhone 4s simulator with iOS 7.1. And I used a breakpoint to check the value of segue.destinationViewController.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, and I didn't find documents about it.

Comment: I ended up doing what Andy said (although my app is now iOS8+ only). Check the class of the segue and use that VC or viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved by checking the class of the destination view controller before trying to access one of its properties:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    DestController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;

    if ([dvc isKindOfClass:[DestController class]])
        dvc.propertyName = @"Property Value";
    else
        // do something else
}
```

Taken from a solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172933/uinavigationcontroller-setgoalname-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-0x) thread.